# Blacklist the fantasy tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-blacklist-request

I don't think I even need to explain why that is, but - just in case - [here's an hyperlink](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/625/how-about-getting-rid-of-the-english-tag).

Comment: Probably this could go in http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag ?

Comment: @TonyMeyer: Similar subject, different question.

Comment: @borrow0 I guess.  It seems like adding "and blacklist them so they can't come back" to that would make it the same, without really changing that post at all :)  Surely sci-fi should be included here?

Comment: @TonyMeyer: It would, but it would be changing Martinho Fernandes' question *and* resuscitating an old question at once. Also, sci-fi, science-fiction, and the like aren't blacklisted? I assumed they were...

Comment: @borrow0 just because a question is old, doesn't mean that it's no longer valuable (true on the main site, true on meta).  IMO it wouldn't have changed the nature of Martinho's question at all, so would have been an appropriate edit/answer.  sci-fi wasn't blacklisted, but now it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I added `^(fantasy|scifi)$` to the tag blacklist as well.

Answer (score 0):

There were only 5 questions tagged [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) (4 of which were closed) and it seemed like people were using them to avoid tagging the questions with something useful.

I've retagged them all, and [fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) [will be automatically pruned daily](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/904/kill-requirments-gathering-and-requirements-engineering) if there are no questions tagged with it.

Comment: It's not status complete. The tag should also be blacklisted, so it is not used in the future.