# Ban on sci-fi and fantasy tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The sci-fi and fantasy tags are currently banned. There have been some discussion about this already, [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380/blacklist-the-fantasy-tag) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag).

The main problem seems to be that these tags are considered too general, that is applying to a large majority of the questions on the site. However, there are some situations in which a similar variant is required to convey meaningful information. For example, in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/a-good-account-of-developmet-of-the-modern-fantasy-genre), I am looking for articles on development and history of the fantasy-genre. So, tagging it with fantasy does make sense because it looks at fantasy as a whole, but there is a ban on the fantasy tag. I request that we unban the fantasy and sci-fi tags, to be used in questions that talk about the genre as a whole.

Comment: We banned the tags because nearly all items on SFF could be tagged with both, for the same reason we became SFF from just SF. It seems impossible to draw a line between them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we need a sci-fi and a fantasy tag?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag)

Comment: I see you used *fantasy-genre*.  What's wrong with that? Or just *genre* or *genre-development*, or *genre-history* (to distinguish from regular history).  You're not asking a question about fantasy any more than any other question, you are asking a question about the genre.

Comment: @Tony- Dampe removed the fantasy-genre tag saying that fantasy tag was banned. (Maybe this is an acceptable compromise). However, as tour suggestion I disagree. In general it's better to use multiple tags instead of joining two tags ( it's a better idea to use star-trek and ftl-drive separately than star-trek-ftl-drive)

Comment: Why the close votes? apoorv020 clearly stated, they want to **revisit** the issue.

Comment: I like @tony 's idea of [genre] or [genre-development]

Comment: @neilfein isn't it more appropriate to have the discussion in the meta post that's already about this than create a new post every time the question comes up? Posting an answer in the existing question will bring it to the top of the active questions list.

Comment: @Tony: but any new answer would start from a score of zero and would have a disadvantage compared to earlier answers.

Comment: @apoorv020 but it would be bumped back to the top, so anyone that cared could change their earlier votes if they wanted to.  Otherwise what's the point of keeping older posts open? Better to build on them than continually re-hash.

Comment: @Tony - There is a clear bias on SE sites against newer answers on existing threads. Attempting to resurrect an older thread is difficult. And not all users view threads by date, some view by votes.