# Do we need "science-fiction-genre" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

These days, whenever I ask a [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) question, next minute I find Gallifreyan (and always Gallifreyan :)) has added the [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre) tag. A quick glance at the [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre) tag shows that it is always there on [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) questions.

Do we really need such redundancy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we need a sci-fi and a fantasy tag?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag)

Comment: @Mooz That question is unrelated - as it currently stands, the tag in question is not used to describe the genre of the work, but for question _about_ the genre itself.

Comment: It's not redundant: [tag:science-fiction-genre] and [tag:fantasy-genre] are two different things. Think of it like putting [tag:books] or [tag:movie] tags on ID questions.

Comment: @Mooz Not a dupe: the [tag:science-fiction-genre] tag is very different from the [tag:science-fiction] tag (the latter is actually blacklisted so that it *can't* be used - try adding it to a question and you should get some sort of error).

Comment: @KutuluMike _<in George Carlin's voice>_ Consistency! Consistency!

Comment: "science-fiction" and "science-fiction-genre" should become amalgamated into one.

Comment: @Mooz As Rand said (and I just tested) - `science-fiction` and `fantasy` are banned, and you can't append them to questions. I think it's for a good reason.

Comment: @KutuluMike The phrase "excessive over-tagging" seems excessive to me. How does "excessive over-tagging" differ from "excessive tagging" or "over-tagging"?

Answer (score 3):

Genre tags are generally accepted, as we do ask questions specifically about those genres using the tags alone, [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) (which was merged with [origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origins)), [trope](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trope), [inspiration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspiration) and others.

We also have a number of other genre tags:

- [horror](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/horror)
- [hard-sci-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-sci-fi)
- [steampunk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steampunk)
- [cyberpunk](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyberpunk)
- [military-sf](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/military-sf)

The thing is to be careful with them, and to make sure the question is actually about the genre as a whole. They're not used to just classify a question such as [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) + [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre), because that's not particularly notable.  The sub-genres I listed above get used with [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) because that  *is* notable, and helps in both finding the questions and researching answers. A parallel is how we use author tags only when the question is about the author, not just about something that the author wrote.

If that's the case, then it *should* be applied. If it's not, it should be removed.

Also, to address another user consistently editing your question's, you may find that I'd do the same to Marvel questions that lacked [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel). Some users just watch different tags than others, depending on their interests.

Comment: ***Why*** aren't genre tags used to classify story-ID questions? The tags on this site seem to be mostly useless, but it could actually be useful to be able to search for military-sf story-id or horror-story id questions.

Comment: @user14111 Because no one does it. The top level genres would be on everything. The subgenres just aren't used much, period.

Comment: For a moment there I thought I'd found a use for tags.

Comment: @user14111 If you add them, they'll be in use. Military-sf is used with story id plenty. The trouble is, it's hard to know the genre of an unknown story if the asker doesn't know, until it's correctly ID'd. And ID questions don't generally get tags edited afterwards (I think there's even a meta about not adding the specific work tag after proper identification)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes we do.

**They are not *redundant*.**

- Just a quick search shows that there are [75 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre+-history-of) with [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre) but without [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of).

  - On the other hand, there are [334 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of+-science-fiction-genre) with [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) but without [science-fiction-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction-genre)
- Another search shows that there are [119 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-genre+-history-of) with [fantasy-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-genre) but without [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of)

  - And [382 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of+-fantasy-genre) with [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of) without [fantasy-genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-genre)

Let's look at usage guidance for all three tags:

- [Science fiction genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/science-fiction-genre/info):

  > Used for questions on the science fiction genre itself, including its tropes and conventions. Should **not** be used to categorize questions about specific works of science fiction.
- [Fantasy genre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/fantasy-genre/info):

  > Used for questions on the fantasy genre itself, including its tropes and conventions. Should **not** be used to categorize questions about specific works of Fantasy.
- [History of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/history-of/info):

  > Use this tag for questions about the history of the genre: the origin and evolution of ideas in speculative fiction. Example topics include the first work of speculative fiction with a particular property, or the origin of a term or trope.

It doesn't look like we can do without any of those three tags: each describes a specific area, and they aren't really interchangeable. One can (sure, why not?)
have a question about the science fiction genre without the `history-of` tag, but it is not hard to see that `history-of` adds a specific description of the question - that the question is interested in the *history* of the genre, not tropes or conventions (hard to draw a line, I admit).

On the other hand, purging the genre tags will certainly leave those ~200 questions orphaned - they will have [history-of](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of), but history of *what*? It looks to me like those three tags were specifically created to work together, and it looks like they're doing a good job.

<sub>Sure, there is always a chance that some of those questions are wrongly tagged, and in fact don't need some of the tags they have, but I find those sample sizes too large to be easily changed by a few mistags.</sub>

There's little chance they'll be used wrongly (I ocasionally see them in first post story-ID questions, but it's not a big deal) since they're no ambiguous - at least they have a tag excerpt that tells you where you *do* use them and where you *don't*.

Comment: I don't quite undesrtand what you're saying, but the choice of tags is in the hands of the asker - if they're willing, they can use either or both. Unlike a qustion about a work of fiction that is either fantasy of science fiction, a question about the genre wouldn't cause controversy, since it's OP's decision to limit the scope of the question.