# Should we blacklist [tag:sci-fi]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I see the tag [sci-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sci-fi) popped up about two weeks ago. As [the consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-tag) [seems to be](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/do-we-need-a-sci-fi-and-a-fantasy-tag), it should not exist.

Can someone nuke it from orbit so it can't come back?

Comment: I don't really see the problem.

Comment: No? It's the **SF&F** SE. I expect _all_ questions here to be marked SF, F, or both. How useful is a pair of tags that between them tag all questions for this SE? Having a tag for [tag:neither-SF-nor-F] would be more useful.

Comment: I agree with @ATS - adding those tags is just noise.

Comment: Im just gonna say ok because i'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I removed the tag, so it will disappear again. I have no objection to blacklisting it, as discussed in the linked (very old now) posts, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should have been kept out by default, but it was only blocking on scifi and not sci-fi, told it to block if there's a dash, too.